# WinRT XAML Find control inside FlipView Item template

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

So I have a flip view to display an article and in this flip view I have a Media Player from the [Microsoft Player Framework](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/). Now I want to be able to access this media player from code.

However, every single example I have found has used FindName on the DataTemplate which WinRT doesn't seen to have.

I have tried

```
var flipViewItem = this.flipView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(flipView.SelectedIndex);
```

and then using the VisualTreeHelper to find the Media Player but `flipViewItem` is always null.

I tried data binding the video player - but this causes all videos in the flip view items to play simultaneously.

Can someone please help?

**EDIT**

So this is my xaml that I am using:

```
<FlipView
        x:Name="flipView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details"
        TabIndex="1"
        Margin="0,127,0,10"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}" Grid.RowSpan="2">

        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <UserControl Loaded="StartLayoutUpdates" Unloaded="StopLayoutUpdates">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}" Grid.Row="1">

                        <common:RichTextColumns x:Name="richTextColumns" Margin="117,0,117,47">
                            <RichTextBlock x:Name="richTextBlock" Width="560" Style="{StaticResource ItemRichTextStyle}">
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Run FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                                </Paragraph>
                                <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">
                                    <InlineUIContainer>
                                        <Grid Width="560" Height="340" Margin="0,20,0,10">
                                            <Grid.Background>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                                            </Grid.Background>
                                            <Image x:Name="OverlayImage" Visibility="{Binding ShowVideo, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Source="Assets/play-icon.png"/>
                                            <mmppf:MediaPlayer x:Name="ArticleVideo" Width="560" Height="340" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </InlineUIContainer>
```

I have tried binding to the media player:

```
<mmppf:MediaPlayer x:Name="ArticleVideo" Source="{Binding VideoPath}" Width="560" Height="340" PosterSource="{Binding Image}" AutoPlay="False" />
```

However, when I do that and set the videos to autoplay - they all autoplay. If I manually press play on the control, I receive a null reference exception at System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler.Invoke. The media player works fine outside the template.

What is confusing, is that I know what I want to is possible. The SkyNews app for windows 8 does exactly what I want to do (add a video to a flip view item template). I had a look in c:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps so see what their xaml looked like at it's the almost the same as mine - with no data binding on the media player. The only difference is that they have x:ConnectionId on the usercontrol and the grid containing the video player in the template. I don't know what x:ConnectionId does - but is it possible they are someone using that to access the controls from their code?

Comment: Have you tried making it a resource and then using `FrameworkElement.FindResource`?

Comment: If I move the MediaPlayer into `<Page.Resources>` how do I then place it in the correct position on my page?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I misunderstood what the component was.

Comment: Have you tried waiting until after the flipview has loaded (i.e. Loaded event)

Comment: Data binding and auxiliary attached properties sound like the way to go, depending on what you are trying to do. What are you trying to do with this media player? What's your XAML so far?

Comment: It's considered polite to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/downloads/get/467926 and look at the VisualTreeHelperExtensions.

There is not direct method to find a the element in the visual tree.  You need to use the VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(flipView, i) method.  Not hard to implement, but the Toolkit has a single extension method class file you can add directly to your project.  It provides a way to get descendants or ancestors by type.  I think it will fit the bill for what you are looking for.

Comment: If you get the descendants by type, it will return all instances of the MediaPlayer. How do you then know which one is in the current FlipView view?

Comment: FlipView should have "currently active item" property, which you can pass then to VisualHelper.FindChild<MediaElement>

Answer (score 0):

Sure. If you want to access a named control in a template - look here http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html